# Google Search Console reports error for 'noindex' tag on sitemap

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, search, noindex, error

My sitemap is dynamically generated by Yoast SEO WordPress plugin, and is returned with `noindex`. I submitted the sitemap URL to Google Search Console, but it reports an error:

> Submitted URL marked ‘noindex’

I checked with Yoast & other sitemap generators--they all mark sitemaps as `noindex` by design, to prevent them from appearing in Google search results. It logically makes sense, but then why is Google Search Console reporting it as an error? How do I reconcile this?

Comment: How are you submitting it in Google Search Console?   Are you using robots.txt, the [inspect URL tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en), the URL submission tool, the [sitemaps tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451001), or something else?

Comment: https://search.google.com/search-console > **Sitemaps** > **Add a new sitemap** > **SUBMIT**

Comment: As long as Google can fetch the sitemap link successful, there no error found and should work probably, its what i readed you use the inspect URL tool for the result.